# Reset interval after clearing it

Tags: javascript, intervals

I have this code:

```
var int1 = setInterval(function () {
    // do stuff

    if(//stuff done){
        clearInterval(int1); 
        setTimeout(
             function () {
                  setInterval(int1)
             }
        ,60000);
    }}
}, 1000)
```

and want the interval to be running again after 60 seconds but `setInterval(int1)` doesn't seem to trigger it again. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: full code: http://pastie.org/8704786

Comment: First you (correctly) call setInterval with a function and an interval, then you (incorrectly) try to call it with only the (integer) return value from setInterval: why would you expect that to work?  Read up on setInterval and re-organize your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd because `int1` is not a function, but an interval id. Try this instead:

```
var int1;
var func = function () {
    // do stuff

    if(//stuff done){
        clearInterval(int1); 
        setTimeout(func, 60000);
    }
};
int1 = setInterval(func, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did 2 mistakes:

1. setInterval whant a function, while int1 contains an interval handle
2. You didn't pass amount of time in your setInterval call

What you want probably is:

```
var int1;

function scheduleStuff() {
    int1 = setInterval(doStuff, 1000);
}


function doStuff() {
    // do stuff

    if(/*stuff done*/){
        clearInterval(int1); 
        setTimeout(scheduleStuff,60000);
    }}
}

scheduleStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

set intervall expectes a function wich is called after waiting time...

this line is wrong:

```
setInterval(int1)
```

no function and no waiting time given...